# I try summary item from object from parent in child components

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Iam starting with this hobby in VUE3 :) I try summary item books.price from object Object is in parent component and I want make this in child components. I have object in App.vue:

```js
<script>
import BooksList from './components/BooksList.vue'
import BooksLengthMsg from './components/BooksLengthMsg.vue'
import booksSummary from './components/BookSummary.vue'
// import { computed } from 'vue'
export default {
  components: { BooksList, BooksLengthMsg, booksSummary },
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    books: [
      {
        title: 'Windows Powershell w miesiąc',
        price: 20
      },
      {
        title: 'Alicja w krainie czarów',
        price: 18
      }
    ],
    form: {
      title: '',
      price: null
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    removeBook (index) {
      this.books.splice(index, 1)
      console.log('delete', index)
    },
    handleSubmit () {
      const newBook = { ...this.form }
      this.books.push(newBook)
      this.resetForm()
    },
    resetForm () {
      this.form.price = null
      this.form.title = ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <h1>Books<span>.app</span></h1>
    </header>
    <books-list @remove="removeBook" :books="books" />
    <books-length-msg :books="books"/>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <label>
        Title:
        <input v-model="form.title" type="text" name="title">
      </label>
      <label>
        Price:
        <input v-model="form.price" type="number" name="price">
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Add book</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <books-summary :books="books" />
</template>
```

and I maked new component  BookSummary and I run Books Amount but I cant run function for total price, I cant save in const priceSummary.

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'BooksSummary',
  setup () {
    const priceSummary = ref(0)
    return { priceSummary }
  },
  props: {
    books: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bookAmount () {
      return this.books.length
    },
    totalPrice () {
    //   const totalPr = this.priceSummary
    //   return this.books.forEach((book) => book.price)
      return this.books.forEach((book) => { console.log(book.price) })
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>Books Amount : {{ bookAmount }}</div>
    <div>Total price : const priceSummary:{{ priceSummary}} function {{ totalPrice }}</div>
</template>
<style>
div {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: according to your script tag at the bottom you're using Vue 2.  Your books-summary component is coded using a mix of Vue 3's Composition API and Vue 2's Options API.   In Vue 2, you should have a `data` property like in your parent component, Vue 2 doesn't know what to do with the `setup()` function.  If you want to write a Vue 3 component, stick with `setup()` but you need to redo your `props` and `computed` properties as that syntax is wrong for Vue 3.

Comment: @yoduh While Vue 2.5.17 script tag at the bottom is misleading, however that is still perfectly functioning Vue 3 component. Both props and computed are valid in Vue 3. [Here it is running on v3.2.26](https://vue-wxzj5v.stackblitz.io)

Comment: In addition, I do agree that @Kotiz should stick with either Options or Composition API, unless transitioning from Vue 2, which in that case all is fine until transition is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `totalPrice` computed property to:

```js
totalPrice () {
  this.priceSummary = this.books.reduce((sum, book) => sum + book.price, 0)
  return this.priceSummary;
}
```

Using .reduce is fairly standard and performant way to get a total from array

[Here is reference for the reduce function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

It was stupid facil error I change { this.priceSummary += book.price }), but now I must make it with reduce (thx for answer) and make parseInt.

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'BooksSummary',
  setup () {
    const priceSummary = ref(0)
    return { priceSummary }
  },
  props: {
    books: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bookAmount () {
      return this.books.length
    },
    totalPrice () {
      return this.books.forEach((book) => { this.priceSummary += book.price })
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>Books Amount : {{ bookAmount }}</div>
    <div>Total price : {{ priceSummary}} {{ totalPrice }}</div>
</template>
<style>
div {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```